# SCRecorder with Swift 2.1 - Cast from 'MDLMaterialProperty?!' to unrelated type

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift2, xcode7.1

When I import the SCRecorder in my project, and compile, I start to receive the Cast from 'MDLMaterialProperty?!' to unrelated type warning in a lot of functions in my project.
I don't why I'm receiving this kind of warning and these are creating a lot of inconsistent when running the app. 
When I remove the SCRecorder everything runs fine.
Anyone can help me?

Using XCode 7.1 with swift 2.1.

Comment: Can you give an example of some code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: SessionManager.sharedInstance.POST(url, parameters: parameters, success: { (dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, response: AnyObject) -> Void in
                    self.login(response["result"] as! NSDictionary, password: nil)
                    block(error: nil)
                    }) { (dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask?, error: NSError) -> Void in

Gives me the warning in response["result"] as! NSDictionary and the app crashes when running this line and it's nothing related to the SCRecorder

Comment: This just happened to me after upgrading to 7.2.  Worked fine before hand. Now all of the keys of my NSDictionaries that I've created from parsing JSON have apparently been turned into MDLMaterialProperty objects and they crash my app repeatedly.